# How to allow lamp and apache2 service run parallel?

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql, lamp

I have a php project in `var/www/html`. It runs when I start `apache2` service is started. But I cannot access phpmyadmin where I have a database that is being used in my php project. (I had to stop lampp for starting apache2 service.) I get this error while accessing phpmyadmin when apache2 service is on. (Php project runs fine without any error.)

[image]

On the other hand, when I need to edit something in database, I use phpmyadmin for which I start lampp(`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`). For doing this I need to stop `apache2` service. And during this time, I cannot run php project. It gives this error.

[image]

Can I do something like letting them work parallel? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to run the apache2 service manually. LAMP is all you need as we all know LAMP = Linux, Apache, Mysql and Php

Comment: When I start only LAMP, i get an error on running the project(shown in second pic).

Comment: checkout the home directory in your Apache config file. By default the home dir is /var/www. Put index.html inside /var/www and check

Answer (score 0):

You could be running two different instances of Apache.  One serving files from var/www/html and the XAMPP/LAMPP instance serving from opt/lampp/htdocs/  (That's the default LAMPP directory)

If you have that directory you could copy your project to it. Then start apache inside of LAMPP and see if it works as expected.

Note: For LLAMP your site might be found here localhost/htdocs

Comment: When I do `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` both apache and mysql will be started. I can access to phpmyadmin at this time. But I am not able to run the project after I do this. To run project, I had to stop lampp and run apache2 service as `sudo service apache2 start`.

Comment: where does the topic state user is using "xampp"? You do realize xampp is a totally different product and it is nothing compared to lamp?

Comment: XAMPP, the all-in-one LAMP project, used to be called LAMPP. Could you be running two different instances of apache.  One serving files from var/www/html and the XAMPP/LAMPP instance serving from opt/lampp/htdocs/  (That's the default lampp directory)